# Grant one IAM role access to a large number of DynamoDB tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an AppSync app defined using a master CloudFormation stack and more than a dozen nested stacks. Each nested stack defines a DynamoDB table, an AppSync DataSource for that table, and an IAM role for that DataSource to access that table. The DataSource depends on the role, which depends on the table.

I would like to consolidate these IAM roles, for three reasons:

- The role definitions are very repetitive and boilerplate-y.
- There are many copies of this app, and it adds up to a lot of IAM roles — enough that we're running close to the soft limits.
- Some resolvers use DynamoDB batch operations to access multiple tables, so at least some of the IAM roles must grant access to multiple tables anyway.

I do not want to give the role blanket access to all DynamoDB tables in the account.

The simplest way to grant one role access to every required table would be to list them manually in the policy document. This has the obvious downside of requiring that the policy be manually kept in sync when new tables are added. However, there is also a dependency problem: the DataSource in a nested stack depends on a role in the master stack, which depends on tables in the nested stacks.

I would have liked to use tags: grant for all DynamoDB tables that have a certain tag, then set that tag for each table. This way, the IAM role would not need to be edited when a new table was added. But apparently [DynamoDB does not support tag-based conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html).

Is there an easy way to grant a single IAM role access to many DynamoDB tables without granting access to all of DynamoDB and without individually listing the tables in the role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can name your tables in a way that gives them the same prefix you can use wildcards in the resource.

```
arn:aws:dynamodb:<Region>:<Account>:table/MyPrefix-*
```

That will work on all tables that start with `MyPrefix-`

If you are using generated names you can probably use the `AWS::StackName` value in place of `MyPrefix` but be aware that with nested stacks that value may get shortened.